# how to close the slidind drawer with the return button - android

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

i try to close the sliding drawer when i click on the return back key but its not working 
here is the code i used

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("onBackPressed Called", FROM_SETTINGS_KEY);
      slidingDrawer.close();

}
```

the xml :

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

so how can i make the return back key close this sliding drawer ?

Comment: Are you throwing an `Exception` or does the `SlidingDrawer` not respond?

Comment: the slidingdrawer not respond and i make the mainactivity not respond to the back key by this code  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
   
  }
  return false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding `Activity.onKeyDown`, [which `Activity` already overrides when implementing `Activity.onBackPressed`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L2111), then returning `false` for `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` which indicates that you have not handled this event and it should continue to be propagated.

To fix your problem stop overriding `Activity.onKeyDown`. Also, change your `Activity.onBackPressed` to call `super` if the `SlidingDrawer` isn't opened.

```
private SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (slidingDrawer.isOpened()) {
        slidingDrawer.close();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3425815 Was this the answer you were looking for? Did you need more help?

Comment: @user3425815 That doesn't make sense. As long as you're not interfering with the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` event, calling `SlidingDrawer.close` in `Activity.onBackPressed` will most definitely close it. Are you possibly forgetting to mention something else that might interfere with the "back" press?

Comment: here is the code i used  @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     if (slidingDrawer.isOpened()) {
         slidingDrawer.close();
     } else {
         super.onBackPressed();
     }
 }
 public boolean onBackPressed(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
  
  }
  return false;
 }
}  its give me force close after click on return back button

Comment: @user3425815 Remove **all** the code that deals with `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`. Only override `onBackPressed` exactly like my answer.

Comment: @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
     if (slidingDrawer.isOpened()) {
         slidingDrawer.close();
     } else {
         super.onBackPressed();
     }
 }} and when i clicked on the return back button gives me force close again and i removed the keyevent code

Comment: @user3425815 I made an edit, make sure you're initializing the `SlidingDrawer` after you call `setContentView`. I'm assuming you're throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: it works thank you very much you was right but its only asked to add cast to sliding drawer  slidingDrawer =  (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer1);  and works fine .. thank you again very much